# jQuery works in Firefox when Firebug is running, does not work when Firebug is NOT running

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I have the following Javascript libraries loaded for my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
```

I have the div element that I want to place them in:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
</div>
```

I have this link:

```
<a id="changeText" href="rules.html">Click to change</a>
```

Finally, I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#changeText").click(function(){

  var url = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#content").load(url);

  console.log(url);

  $.scrollTo("0%", 400);
 });
});
</script>
```

This all works in Safari. The oddest part of the story is that it only works in Firefox when Firebug is on. When Firebug is NOT on, the page seems to be dynamically loaded, but then the page loads rules.html and switches to it, which is not my desired goal.

Also, of course, none of this works in IE8.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'd better wrap all your

```
console.log(...)
```

into

```
if (window.console) {
    console.log(...);
}
```

Comment: +1 I liked this answer as it offered a work-around which would allow both scenarios to function properly.

Comment: I do something similar where i have a function called log() which will check if window.console is available and if so log the command.

Comment: Saved my day. It's fine on Firefox 4.0 though :)

Answer (score 11):

Take out the console.log, it is undefined when firebug is not running.

Comment: I also needed to add:

return false;

at the end of my function. Otherwise the browser would load up rules.html

Comment: Yeah, the console object only exists in Safari and Firefox when Firebug is on. You need to strip out the console.log call.

Comment: And more generally: look in the Error Console to debug problems, it would've told you there was no console.log().

Comment: If you were to look _in_ the error console, wouldn't that automatically make the console.log work?

Comment: No. "Error console" refers to the built-in Error console in Firefox. It's not the Firebug equivalent. You can find it by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + J` or `Tools > Error Console` in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have a console before trying to use it.

Bind a Boolean variable so:

```
var hasConsole = (typeof console != 'undefined' && typeof console.log != 'undefined');
```

And check it before writing to the console:

```
   if (hasConsole) {
      console.log("This is safe.");
   }
```

This way when you turn on Firebug you get your debug messages and when you turn it off your scripts still work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to mask missing logging functions.

```
if (typeof console === "undefined") {
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];

    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also there is interesting project called [fauxconsole](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/fauxconsole): Simulating a Firebug, Safari or Opera debugging console in Microsoft Internet Explorer with Faux Console